# Glassfish is not working on ReadHat Server

Tags: java, linux, glassfish, redhat

I am trying to install Glassfish 4.0 on a Linux Red Hat Entreprise Linux release 5.11 (Tikanga) Server.

Therefore, I successfully installed Java jdk1.7.0_79 and NetBeans 4.0 on this server following this website instructions: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/02/tutorial-setting-up-glassfish-on-a-linux-server/

When I run the server using the linux command **./asadmin start-domain**, the console tells me that everything is ok:
[image]

If I run the **sudo netstat -lntp** command, I obtain the following output for port 4848:

[image]

which seems to be all right.

Finally, if I open the **domain.xml** file in **glassfish/domains/domain1/config** repertory, I will have:
[image]

and
[image]

and
[image]

which is quite strange because port 4848 is not appearing and everything is set to **localhost**.

I really do not know what is going on. In the tutorial everything looked so straightforward. Could you help me please ?

Comment: What have you done to investigate this so far? Some questions to consider: [1] Is the server definitely running? Check with `sudo netstat -lntp` to see if port 4848 is occupied. Also check the server log to make sure it started correctly. [2] Are you trying to connect to a remote server? If so, you need to enable secure admin and open the console over https.

Comment: Thank you for your help Mike. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The admin console port is set as [a network listener under the network-config in the domain.xml](http://i.imgur.com/UwYut0J.png). You might want to check that the server you are connecting to accepts connections on port 4848

Comment: I've run on the server the tcpdump -i eth0 port 4848 command in order to see the traffic getting in the server. The 4848 seems to be opened. I do not have any error message.

Comment: There's nothing blocking traffic from outside the network local to your server though? What about the other ports, can you access GlassFish on port 8080? There is a default page there even when nothing is deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the problem.

The firewall of my Linux Red Hat Entreprise Linux release 5.11 was blocking the 4848 port. Therefore, using the following commands I successfully made everything working properly:

1. Go to the following folder:

> /etc/sysconfig

2. Open the file containing the firewall table:

> vi iptables

3. Add the following line to the table:

> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state –-state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -–dport 4848 -j ACCEPT

4. Save and exit
5. Restart the network service by typing :

> service iptables restart